# How to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix with SymPy?

Tags: python, matrix, system, sympy

I want to calculate the eigenvectors **x** from a system *A* by using this: *A* **x** = *λ* **x**

The problem is that I don't know how to solve the eigenvalues by using SymPy.
Here is my code. I want to get some values for x1 and x2 from matrix `A`

```
from sympy import *
x1, x2, Lambda = symbols('x1 x2 Lambda')
I = eye(2)
A = Matrix([[0, 2], [1, -3]])
equation = Eq(det(Lambda*I-A), 0)
D = solve(equation)
print([N(element, 4) for element in D]) # Eigenvalus in decimal form
print(pretty(D)) # Eigenvalues in exact form

X = Matrix([[x1], [x2]]) # Eigenvectors
T = A*X - D[0]*X # The Ax = %Lambda X with the first %Lambda = D[0]
print(pretty(solve(T, x1, x2)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sympy has a very convenient way of getting eigenvalues and eigenvectors: [sympy-doc](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/matrices.html)

Your example would simply become:

```
from sympy import *
A = Matrix([[0, 2], [1, -3]])
print(A.eigenvals())  #returns eigenvalues and their algebraic multiplicity
print(A.eigenvects())  #returns eigenvalues, eigenvects
```

Comment: [T, D] = A.diagonalize() was a better method in SymPy.

Answer (score 9):

The methods [`eigenvals`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.eigenvals) and [`eigenvects`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.eigenvects) is what one would normally use here.

`A.eigenvals()` returns `{-sqrt(17)/2 - 3/2: 1, -3/2 + sqrt(17)/2: 1}` which is a dictionary of eigenvalues and their multiplicities. If you don't care about multiplicities, use `list(A.eigenvals().keys())` to get a plain list of eigenvalues.

The output of `eigenvects` is a bit more complicated, and consists of triples (eigenvalue, multiplicity of this eigenvalue, basis of the eigenspace). Note that the multiplicity is [algebraic multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity), while the number of eigenvectors returned is the [geometric multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspaces.2C_geometric_multiplicity.2C_and_the_eigenbasis_for_matrices), which may be smaller. The eigenvectors are returned as 1-column matrices for some reason...

For your matrix, `A.eigenvects()` returns the eigenvector `[-2/(-sqrt(17)/2 + 3/2),  1]` for the eigenvalue `-3/2 + sqrt(17)/2`, and eigenvector `[-2/(3/2 + sqrt(17)/2), 1]` for  eigenvalue `-sqrt(17)/2 - 3/2`.

If you want the eigenvectors presented as plain lists of coordinates, the following

```
[list(tup[2][0]) for tup in A.eigenvects()]
```

would output `[[-2/(-sqrt(17)/2 + 3/2), 1], [-2/(3/2 + sqrt(17)/2), 1]]`. (Note this just picks one eigenvector for each eigenvalue, which is not always what you want)

Comment: Hi! Yes, i Know how to get the eigenvects by using the built in functions. But if I want to use the solve-function. As you see, it's not working for me. I cannot calculate out x1 and x2 which is the eigenvectors.

Comment: The above line doesnt always work, for example for this matrix there are 3 Eign vectors and that line above shows me only 2.

```
A = Matrix([
    [4, 0, 1],
    [2, 3, 2],
    [1, 0, 4]
])
```

Comment: This line worked for me best
```
    sym_eignvects = []
    for tup in sMatrix.eigenvects():
        for v in tup[2]:
            sym_eignvects.append(list(v))
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help you when you all eignvectors, the solution above doesnt always give you all eienvectos for example this matrix A used below

```py
# the matrix
A = Matrix([
    [4, 0, 1],
    [2, 3, 2],
    [1, 0, 4]
])
```

```
    sym_eignvects = []
    for tup in sMatrix.eigenvects():
        for v in tup[2]:
            sym_eignvects.append(list(v))
```